# How do I create a textfield that will display an integer and text?

Tags: actionscript, text

I am trying to make a textfield to display the player's score.  I call the textfield "score", and want it to display "Player Score: *[score]*".

Right now, my code looks like this:

```
score.text = String "Player Score:" (scoreValue);
```

This isn't working, but I feel that it must be very close.  What is the proper method for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably searching for the **[toString()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/int.html#toString%28%29)** function

```
var scoreValue:uint = 1234;
trace("Player Score: "+scoreValue.toString());
```

Should print: *Player Score: 1234*

```
score.text = "Player Score: "+scoreValue.toString();
```

is probably what you need.

Comment: You can actually skip the `toString()` method, as it will automatically be called when concatenating numbers and strings.. eg. `"Player Score: " + scoreValue` will work as well.